# Does the loader rewrite absolute addresses in machine code?

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, relocation, aslr

Let's say I have the following:

a pref. Image base of 0x40000 and the fact that ASLR is being used.

am I correct if I say that translation would be done like this:

```
(OG)

0004232f 8b 45 00                     MOV          EAX,dword ptr [EBP]
00042332 a3 64 00 6C 00               MOV          [006C0064],EAX                                 
00042337 8b 45 04                     MOV          EAX,dword ptr [EBP + 0x4]

(After ASLR)

0066232f 8b 45 00                     MOV          EAX,dword ptr [EBP]
00662332 a3 64 20 72 00               MOV          [00722064],EAX                                 
00662337 8b 45 04                     MOV          EAX,dword ptr [EBP + 0x4]
```

is there anything else I overlook that could change the byte order on load?

Comment: What loader?  Are you talking about Linux PIE executables?  Also, x86 doesn't have absolute `call`.  It has absolute addressing modes for data accesses, which you're using.

Comment: I'm talking about Windows - loader being the execute loader as absolute call I mean that whatever it be a mov, or sub is done via an absolute address not offset - hence I ask what else is not static / is being changed (if there is any) - and who exactly does it as the loader was just my guess

Comment: If you mean an absolute addressing mode, then don't say "call", say "address".  I'd assume that the Windows kernel's PE program-loader itself applies relocation fixups for an executable; possibly also for a DLL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 32-bit Windows all `DLL` files and many (but not all) `EXE` files have a so-called "Base Relocation Table".

This table contains a list of all absolute addresses contained in the file.

In your example, there is an absolute address (`0x006C0064`) stored at address `0x00042333`.

The table will contain an entry saying that there is an absolute address stored at `0x00042333`.

When the executable file or dynamic library is loaded to another address, the loader will indeed "rewrite" all these addresses.

However, "rewriting" is a quite simple operation: A fixed value must simply be added to all these addresses.

Please note that this concept is completely different from the concept used by Linux and other OSs.

Comment: Thank you very much